# Can I successfully freeze raw cabbage?

Tags: freezing

How long will an half of raw cabbage last in the freezer? Had leftover after making stuffed cabbage rolls, will be making corned beef & cabbage for St. Paddy's Day. Will it make it?

Comment: Is it half a head or is it already cut up? To be honest, if it's still a half of a head, I think it would likely be fine in the fridge though you'll want to re-cut the open side.

Comment: Hi Catija... It's half an head. I'm fortunate to have a great grocery store whose produce is fab.. (huge & fresh).. So I only needed half of it for my dinner & that's after shredding some for the bedding of casserole dish.. which is optional... So, you think it'll last in fridge until 3/15, 16 or 17th?? I can wedge it, shred it or whatever.. Just don't want it dying a slow death in my crisper:-D

Comment: Chop it up. Add some salt. Stuff it in a jar and sauerkraut will appear. That's my go to for leftover cabbage (the technique is as old as time). Search 'lacto sauerkraut' if that tickles your fancy.

Answer (score 2):

You can freeze raw cabbage and keep it for months, however it's not good for the texture as freezing damages the structure. You're better off keeping it in the fridge or just using it. It may make it to St. Patrick's day in the fridge but it will lose some flavor, I'd suggest using it and buying more then.

Answer (score 2):

You can freeze cabbage after you blanch it. I do, but I like cooked cabbage. It will change it a little. It's a little tougher but still taste great. Can only be used for cooking. I cut mine to the size I want before the freezing process. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest freezing cabbage raw.  You're better off [quartering and blanching it](http://www.hgtvgardens.com/freezing/freezing-cabbage).

For the 2 weeks that you're looking at 'til St. Patricks day, if it hasn't already spent months at the store, you should be fine with it in the fridge, wrapped in plastic.

(although cabbage is useful & cheap enough item that it's worth using what you have and buying another head next week ... or buy brussel sprouts if you want an easier way to get a specific quantity of cabbage without waste.)

Answer (score 1):

I cut out the hard end of the core, then wrap in plastic wrap and freeze whole cabbage. Thaw and peel off limp leaves for stuffed cabbage rolls. No blanching needed. I add about 5-10 extra minutes cooking time to the cabbage rolls.

Answer (score 0):

Cabbage stored in a freezer tends to be watery and limp when thawed. We would never store cabbage in our freezers.

Answer (score -2):

Freezing cabbage only makes it limp & wet, because the cells contain water, and you know what happens when water freezes...it expands, and would burst the cells in the cabbage, creating watery & limp cabbage when thawed. My Mom used to freeze tomatoes... run them under warm water & the skin would rub right off, once the tomato was all thawed, She would "core" it & serve cold like diced tomatoes out of a can with salt & pepper & no lost flavor!